# Getting files with Office-365-SDK-for-Java

Tags: java, office365, microsoft-graph-api, office365api, onedrive

I'm trying to get my files on OneDrive using special SDK for Java.

https://github.com/OfficeDev/Office-365-SDK-for-Java

There are 2 examples in this library to post file and then get it by ID, but what about getting list of files to work with? I tried Files and Drive resources with executing read and get operation, but there are errors.

What I try to do:

```
JavaDependencyResolver javaDependencyResolver = new . 
JavaDependencyResolver(token.getAccessToken());
GraphServiceClient client = new 
GraphServiceClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0", javaDependencyResolver);
client.getUsers().getById(idToken.getObjectId()).getFiles().readRaw().get()
```

The error I get:

```
com.microsoft.services.orc.core.OrcException: Response status: 400
Response content: {
"error": {
"code": "BadRequest",
"message": "Unsupported segment type. ODataQuery: users('{ID}')/files",
"innerError": {
  "request-id": "4a8da651-03ee-4ca3-b17f-75460c3b09d6",
  "date": "2017-07-11T12:27:25"
}
}
}
```

Does this library provide functionality to iterate through files? What the API should be used to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This library is not currently supported by Microsoft. I would recommend using the [Microsoft Graph](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-android) library for this.

You can query files like this:

```
graph.getMe().getDrive().getItems().buildRequest().get();
```

Comment: Is that compatible with Java EE projects?

Comment: Is Microsoft going to support Java library?

Comment: It currently does not. We are working on creating a Java library as well